# Removing course and relationship

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to remove courses/sections/lessons with soft delete
I have on tables:

```
$table->softDeletes();
```

And in models:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

use HasFactory, SoftDeletes;

protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
```

Destroy function:

```
  public function courseDestroy(Course $course)
    {
        foreach($course->sections as $section){
            foreach($section->lessons as $lesson){
              $lesson->delete();
            }
            $section->delete();
          }
          $course->delete();
        return redirect('/all-courses');
    }
```

Route:

```
 Route::delete('/course/remove/{id}', [CourseManagementController::class, 'courseDestroy'])->name('course.destroy');
```

And blade:

```
<form action="/course/remove/{{$course->id}}" method="POST">
            @csrf
            @method('DELETE')
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
          </form>
```

But it don't working it's only redirecting me back...

Comment: It seems you aren't using any model instance in your courseDestroy method

Answer (score 0):

I had problem with

```
 Route::delete('/course/remove/{id}', [CourseManagementController::class, 'courseDestroy'])->name('course.destroy');
```

I changed {id} with {course} and it's now working : )